# Query on consequences of $\mathsf{P=BPP}$

Tags: complexity-theory

We know $\mathsf{P=BPP} \implies \mathsf{NEXP\not\subseteq P/Poly}$ or permanent does not have polynomial sized circuits. However permanent needs superpoly circuits imply $\mathsf{NEXP\not\subseteq P/Poly}$ since $\mathsf{P^{\#P}\subseteq  PSPACE\subseteq NEXP}$. So why dont we just say $\mathsf{P=BPP} \implies \mathsf{NEXP\not\subseteq P/Poly}$?

Comment: Where have you seen "... or permanent does not have polynomial sized circuits"?  (I've only seen "... or permanent does not have polynomial sized _arithmetic_ circuits".)

Comment: @RickyDemer is it not true if permanent does not have poly size arith ckts then nexp is not in p/poly?

Comment: That implication is probably true, since its conclusion is probably true.

Comment: @RickyDemer ' probably true' is different from already known. is it not already known?

Comment: (Bear in mind that your earlier comment only asked about truth.)  Yes, that's not already known.

Comment: @RickyDemer so poly sized artih ckts does not imply poly sized boolean ckts or vice versa?

Comment: By modular arithmetic, for polynomial-length output, poly-size division-free arithmetic circuits imply poly-size Boolean circuits.

Comment: @RickyDemer Then if permanent does not have *division* free poly sized arith ckts when would it follow $\mathsf{NEXP\not\subseteq P/poly}$?

Comment: Should "follow" be replaced with "follow that"?  In any case, I now realize the circuit result I mentioned would also apply to [circuits with division that work even when the division gates can provide arbitrary output when [the divisor is zero or the quotient is not at integer]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is that the permanent does not have polynomial-size (constant-free) *arithmetic* circuits or $\mathsf{NEXP} \not\subseteq \mathsf{P/poly}$. Permanent not having polynomial-size constant-free arithmetic circuits is not known to imply $\mathsf{NEXP} \not\subseteq \mathsf{P/poly}$.

However, there are a couple more recent similar results whose conclusion is not a disjunction, but simply a lower bound on some polynomial family in $\mathsf{NEXP}$:

- [Jansen and Santhanam](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/135/) showed that if PIT is in $\mathsf{NSUBEXP}$ then there is a family of polynomial whose integer evaluation problem is in $\mathsf{NEXP}$ but which do not have poly-size constant-free arithmetic circuits.
- [Carmosino, Impagliazzo, Kabanets, and Kolokolova](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2015/5328/) show that if PIT over a fixed finite field is in $\mathsf{NSUBEXP}$ then there is a multilinear polynomial whose evaluation problem over that same finite field is in $\mathsf{NE}$ that does not have poly-size arithmetic circuits. (This paper also has many other results of interest, including true hardness-to-randomness *equivalences*, avoiding many of the usual caveats.)

Comment: @joshuagrchow does $\mathsf{NEXP}$ not having poly-size constant-free arithmetic circuits with some *additional* condition known to imply $\mathsf{NEXP}\not\subseteq\mathsf{P/poly}$? If so what is that *additional* condition?

Comment: @Turbo: Not as far as I know. Most of the big implications show that a Boolean circuit lower bound implies an arithmetic circuit lower bound, not the other way around (which makes sense intuitively, since arithmetic circuits are a restricted model).

Comment: so moral is the original P=BPP implications is the real deal or else (or anything lower than that) will not have NEXP not in P/Poly as an implication.